# Deploying JAR in FuseESB gets ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, maven, apache-camel, apache-karaf, fuseesb

I've got this in my camel-cxf.xml file:

```
<bean id="configFile" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="file:${karaf.home}/etc/test.cfg"/>
</bean>
```

test.cfg is there.  My pom.xml has the following, which resolves to version 2.12.0.redhat-610379:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It all compiles fine.  But when I drop it in Fuse's deploy folder, I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not found by myService [257]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
```

So I presume it's my OSGi not having camel/spring, but I have now done 'features:install X' for every possible variation of camel and spring, and it doesn't change anything.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to import the package of org.apache.camel.spring.spi in your bundle.

Comment: I import camel-spring already in the pom...  if I look in the maven jar, it has org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (.class)

Comment: No, you need to update the bundle manifest file for it. Please take a look at the camel-example-osgi, the maven bundle plugin can help you generate right bundle manifest.

Comment: hmm, no luck yet.  I added the build-helper-maven-plugin and the features.xml from camel-example-osgi.  I then got: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.Processor not found".  I'll work on it more tomorrow.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at setting of maven bundle from the camel parent. https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/parent/pom.xml#L2724  It can help you to setup right manifest.

Comment: Hey Willem, thanks, yeah I ended up finding a way to deploy non-OSGi bundles in FUSE.  I'm sure I'll find a need to deploy an OSGi bundle some time, so I will check back on this answer some day.